# Trying to plot correlation matrix using corrplot() in R

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am trying to plot a correlation matrix, however, I keep getting this error:

"Can't combine `col1`  and `correlation` "

Here is my code:

```
college_df <- read.csv("/home/jovyan/data/college_scorecard.csv")
college_df_num <- select_if(college_df, is.numeric)

get_cor <- function(df, cor) {
    cor_df <- df %>% 
        as.matrix %>%
        cor %>%
        as.data.frame %>%
        rownames_to_column(var = 'col1') %>%
        pivot_longer(-col1, names_to = "col2", values_to = "correlation") %>%
        filter(col1 != col2, correlation > cor)
    return(cor_df)
}

test <- get_cor(college_df_num, .6)
```

Here is the output from the above function:

```
A tibble: 20 × 3
col1    col2    correlation
<chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
PCIP23  PCIP45  0.6314775
PCIP23  PCIP54  0.6908904
PCIP27  PCIP45  0.6298949
PCIP45  PCIP23  0.6314775
PCIP45  PCIP27  0.6298949
PCIP45  PCIP54  0.6303457
PCIP54  PCIP23  0.6908904
PCIP54  PCIP45  0.6303457
NPT LOAN_EVER   0.6822869
```

I am using data from the the American College Scorecard data set (https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/).

is there anyway to plot the correlation output either using corrplot or another library?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide an excerpt of your data. Otherwise you won't receive any replies, as nobody knows the structure of your initial data.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, updated with excerpt of code.

Comment: The issue is that `corrplot::corrplot` expects a correlation matrix as argument, i.e. the result of ` ... %>% cor()`, not a dataframe in tidy or long format which is the result returned by your function.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you want to first convert the adjacency list to an adjacency matrix, and then plot the matrix with the corrplot function. There is a thing to consider here, whether your adjacency matrix happens to be a square one. If it is, use

```
library(circlize)
library(corrplot)

college_df_mat <- adjacencyList2Matrix(college_df_num, square = TRUE)
corrplot(college_df_mat, is.corr=FALSE)
```

If it isn't, use

```
library(circlize)
library(corrplot)

college_df_mat <- adjacencyList2Matrix(college_df_num, square = FALSE)
corrplot(college_df_mat, is.corr=TRUE)
```